# How can i create a design to comunication site with custom layout to home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, design, site-creation

I know that i can create scripts and designs for types of sites (comunication or team site). I can config default themes, create lists etc.

However i did not find a way to config the home page layout automatically. I see that when a choose to create a comunication site they have different home page layout for each design, so i image that this is possible, but did not find a way to do it.

[image]
﻿
[image]

Someone as able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Customisation of pages is not yet supported in site designs.

One option would be to apply a provisioning template once the site is created.

[About the PnP provisioning engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)

More reading: [Calling the PnP provisioning engine from a site script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-pnp-provisioning)

Answer (score 0):

The following article will help you better understand the association between site design and pnp template：

https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2018/01/site-designs-scripts-or-pnp-templates.html